# Test if netcat listener got a connection and run a command locally

Tags: bash, netcat

I need a way to fire a netcat listener from a shell script and if a connection received I need to run a command on the same local listener machine and without interrupting the netcat process / connection
it's like the -e option but I need to run a command locally while keeping the netcat connection running

I don't really know if it can be done I mean after the shell process forked the netcat child can it interact with nc's output for example and run other command before netcat exit?

Edit: I figured it's even easier to do it on the client C code side by checking the return value of an initial send() message to determine if the client connected successfully if we got the sent message length

```
sret = send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
if (sret == strlen(message)) // We're Connected
   do something
```

Thanks

Comment: What if the connection drops out whilst your script is running? And does the connection need to be stopped after the script has finished? If you were only looking to see if a netcat connection could be made, then this would be easier.

Comment: This looks like what you might need: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/howto-create-a-permanent-client-connection-with-netcat

Comment: Netcat needs to be kept running until stopped by demand and there is no problem if the shell script will keep running in a while loop too

Comment: Take a look at that link I sent above - it uses 2 files to handle the input/output for the netcat command that's being forked.

Comment: Checking it out now, Thanks

Comment: I don't think I can apply that with a netcat listener "nc -lvp 1234" I want to run a curl get call as soon as a connection received by the listener while keeping the netcat process running

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the initial `nc` process has started listening, and it will echo every line of input it receives and will then send back a `Received` response:

```
rm -f input.txt
touch input.txt

tail -f input.txt | nc -l 5555 > output.txt &

if ! ps -p $! >/dev/null; then
    echo "Netcat didn't start. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

tail -f output.txt | while read -r LINE; do
    echo "Received input: $LINE"
    echo "Received" >> input.txt
done
```

See if you can adapt this to meet your needs.

Comment: :( the problem is that I need netcat in the foreground to interact with

Comment: Apologies, I thought the script was interacting with it? With the current example you can `echo command >> input.txt`. Can you update your question with an example use case and I'll try and come up with a better solution.